# How to get the the 1st, 2nd and 5th element from an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How should I get the 1st, 2nd and 5th element from an array? Is there a very easy way to do it?

Comment: Doing the same as you would in several other languages: indexing the array using `n-1` for the `Nth` item.

Comment: You should browse the Ruby Array class documentation. :)

Comment: @PabloMarambio It's definitely not the same as other languages.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
p ['a','b','c','d','e'].values_at(0,1,4) #=> ["a", "b", "e"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exactly what I am looking for! How nice Ruby is!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as every other language.

```
irb(main):001:0> array = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'purple']
=> ["blue", "red", "green", "orange", "purple"]
irb(main):002:0> array[0]
=> "blue"
irb(main):003:0> array[1] 
=> "red"
irb(main):004:0> array[4]
=> "purple"
```

Next time check the official documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html.